# Implementing recursive generator for simple tree structure in Swift

Tags: swift, recursion, swift2, generator

I have a simple tree structure in memory based on an XML document and I am trying to write a recursive generator to support `SequenceType`, but I am stuck on how to actually do this.

Here was my first attempt:

```
@objc public class XMLNode: NSObject, SequenceType {
    public weak var parentNode: XMLNode?
    public var nodeName: String
    public var attributes: [String: String]
    public var childNodes = [XMLNode]()

    public func generate() -> AnyGenerator<XMLNode> {
        var childGenerator = childNodes.generate()
        var returnedSelf = false

        return anyGenerator {
            let child = childGenerator.next()

            if child != nil {
                // I need to somehow recurse on child here

                return child
            } else if !returnedSelf {
                returnedSelf = true
                return self
            } else {
                return nil
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Since `childNodes` is an array, I'm calling its own built-in `generate()` function to create a generator on the child nodes and iterating it, and then returning `self` at the end. The problem is it's not recursing on each child, so it only ever goes one level deep. I can't figure out how to combine two generators in that way.

I'm having a hard time wrapping my head around how to do this! What do I need to do to make a recursive generator?

Comment: How is `childNodes` defined? And what is `self` (in `return self`)? – Perhaps you can provide a (stripped-down) *self-contained* example of the tree structure, that would make it easier to find (and test) a possible solution.

Comment: What nature of tree traversal are you trying to do?

Comment: Basically a depth-first pre- or post-order traversal, but that's not terribly important.

Comment: How would you populate this to a repetitive UITableView?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>I don't know if a generator itself can be recursive.</strike> 
 Will M [proved me wrong](https://stackoverflow.com/a/35279624/1187415)!

Here is a possible implementation for a pre-order traversal, using a stack for the  child nodes which still have to be enumerated:

```
extension XMLNode : SequenceType {
    public func generate() -> AnyGenerator<XMLNode> {
        var stack : [XMLNode] = [self]
        return anyGenerator {
            if let next = stack.first {
                stack.removeAtIndex(0)
                stack.insertContentsOf(next.childNodes, at: 0)
                return next
            }
            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

For a level-order traversal, replace

```
stack.insertContentsOf(next.childNodes, at: 0)
```

by

```
stack.appendContentsOf(next.childNodes)
```

Comment: This is working great for pre-order, and is way simpler than my attempt! Cheers!

Comment: Addressing your first line, I think my answer is a recursive generator, but I'm not 100% confident that I didn't cheat somewhere to make it not truly recursive

Comment: @WillM.: I think you are right. It took me a while to wrap my head around it :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is a recursive post-order generator. Can't say I'd recommend actually using it though. 
@MartinR's answer seems a bit more practical

```
 public func generate() -> AnyGenerator<XMLNode> {
    var childGenerator:AnyGenerator<XMLNode>?
    var childArrayGenerator:IndexingGenerator<[XMLNode]>? = self.childNodes.generate()
    var returnedSelf = false

    return anyGenerator {
        if let next = childGenerator?.next() {
            return next
        }
        if let child = childArrayGenerator?.next() {
            childGenerator = child.generate()
            return childGenerator?.next()

        } else if !returnedSelf {

            returnedSelf = true
            return self

        } else {

            return nil
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I actually just managed to get a similar implementation working! But I think you are right, @MartinR's stack solution seems much simpler.

Answer (score 1):

While Martin's answer is certainly more concise, it has the downside of making a lot of using a lot of array/insert operations and is not particularly usable in lazy sequence operations.  This alternative should work in those environments, I've used something similar for `UIView` hierarchies.

```
public typealias Generator = AnyGenerator<XMLNode>

public func generate() -> AnyGenerator<XMLNode> {
    var childGenerator = childNodes.generate()
    var subGenerator : AnyGenerator<XMLNode>?
    var returnedSelf = false

    return anyGenerator {
        if !returnedSelf {
            returnedSelf = true
            return self
        }

        if let subGenerator = subGenerator,
            let next = subGenerator.next() {
                return next
        }

        if let child = childGenerator.next() {
            subGenerator = child.generate()
            return subGenerator!.next()
        }

        return nil
    }
}
```

Note that this is preorder iteration, you can move the `if !returnedSelf` block around for post order.

Comment: Good point re: the array inserts, and this has the benefit of being easily convertible between pre- and post-order, as does @WillM.'s answer.