# Recursively loop through array of arrays using functional

Tags: ios, swift

I want to loop through my view subviews, and for each subview loop through its subviews and etc.

so let say I have the following code:

```
let view = myVC.view
view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
```

then repeat this same for each subview. I want to do it functionally.

any insight is much appreciated.

EDIT:

to make it clear

I'm looking for something like this:

```
view.subviews.chanageColor() { (aView, aColor) in
aView.backgroundColor = aColor
}
```

but it should be recursive it goes to each view subview.

Comment: It doesn't make sense to do this though. It would make more sense to pass a cooler into a recursive function.

Comment: What benefit do you get from doing this "functionally"?

Comment: @Fogmeister Maybe nothing. I just wanna do it "functionally" because I can do it recursively plus I'm weak at functional swift.

Comment: OK, check out my answer. It may do what you want?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Use a queue instead of recursing.

I think you could do something like this...

```
extension UIView {    
    func changeColor(color: UIColor) {
        var queue = [self]

        while let view = queue.first() {
            queue += view.subviews

            view.backgroundColor = color

            queue.remove(view)
        }
    }
}
```

I'd do it with a queue instead of doing it recursively. That method isn't functional though.

### Doing what your question wanted

You could do this way, which is what you put in your question as what you wanted to do.

```
extension UIView {
    // this name isn't very good but you get the idea
    func applyChangeToAllSubviews(block: (UIView) -> ()) {
        var queue = [self]

        // I don't have my dev computer dos not sure of the syntax
        while let view = queue.first() {
            queue += view.subviews

            block(view)

            queue.remove(view)
        }
    }
}
```

Then run it like...

```
someView.applyChangeToAllSubviews {
    view in
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
}
```

I guess that's a bit more functional... ish.

Comment: I have used your solution as an inspiration for recursive-functional swift answer :) It was more like an edit though, however I used Array extension.

Answer (score 4):

Something like this?

```
func makeAllSubviewsClear(view: UIView!)
{
    view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    for eachSubview in view.subviews
    {
        makeAllSubviewsClear(eachSubview)
    }
}
```

called via:

```
let view = myVC.view
makeAllSubviewsClear(view)
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer, but this is recursive. it is not functional

Comment: What's not functional about a one line call into a recursive method? Perhaps the question was a little confusing.

Answer (score 1):

How about follwing:

```
let _ = myVC.view.subviews.map{ $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor() }
```

Although map should be used differently imho.

EDIT: 
I've just looked that the OP wanted recursive loop which is different thing. You should move this code into function and call it recursively for each $0.

Something like this perhaps:

```
extension Array where Element: UIView {
    func changeColor(color: UIColor) {
        for view in self {
            view.subviews.changeColor(color)
            view.backgroundColor = color
        }
    }
}
```

Looks functional and can be called like this:

```
myVC.view.subviews.changeColor(color)
```

**Inspired by @fogmaister one more solution:**

```
extension Array where Element: UIView {
    func applyChange(closure: (UIView)->()) {
        for view in self {
            view.subviews.applyChange(closure)
            closure(view)
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Cool, I was thinking of doing this also. :D

Answer (score 0):

Here is a possible generic solution which allows to
traverse any "nested sequence". It is not restricted to `UIView`
and `subviews`, but takes a parameter which maps each sequence element to its immediate children.

It also separates the task of *traversing* the sequence from the
*action* on the elements (like setting a background color), by returning a `Generator` which
can be used with existing methods like `forEach()`.

(This is inspired by some answers to [Implementing recursive generator for simple tree structure in Swift](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35278610/implementing-recursive-generator-for-simple-tree-structure-in-swift).)

```
extension SequenceType {

    public func generate<S : SequenceType where S.Generator.Element == Generator.Element>
        (children children: Generator.Element -> S) -> AnyGenerator<Generator.Element> {

            var selfGenerator = self.generate()
            var childGenerator : AnyGenerator<Generator.Element>?

            return anyGenerator {
                // Enumerate all children of the current element:
                if childGenerator != nil {
                    if let next = childGenerator!.next() {
                        return next
                    }
                }

                // Get next element of self, and prepare subGenerator to enumerate its children:
                if let next = selfGenerator.next() {
                    childGenerator = children(next).generate(children: children)
                    return next
                }

                return nil
            }
    }
}
```

As an example, if `view` is a `UIView` then

```
view.subviews.generate(children: { $0.subviews })
```

returns a (lazy) generator of all (nested) subviews. By calling `forEach()` on this generator, we can modify each subview:

```
view.subviews.generate(children: { $0.subviews }).forEach {
    $0.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

But it could also be used to get an array with all nested subviews:

```
let allViews = Array(view.subviews.generate(children: { $0.subviews }))
```